# How do I return value of a key of an object dynamically in typescript?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

I intended to show value of some selected keys of an object array.

here is my code:

```
this.gData.GetAll(this.selected.value)
  .subscribe(
    x => {
      x.forEach(
        y => {
          const len = Object.keys(y).length;
          for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (this.findInCoulumns(Object.keys(y)[i]) === true) {
              console.log({'obj ' : y.Object.keys(y)[i]}); // => What should I write here?
            }
          }
        }
      );
    }
  )
```

`findInCoulumns` function checks if column is in the seleted columns list to show or not.

I want to show value of `Object.keys(y)[i]` key and I think `y.Object.keys(y)[i]` is not true.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keys=Object.keys(y)` will give you array of keys of `y`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Than, you can use those keys to access value in object like

```
y[keys[i]]
```